# Android layout wrap_content with layout_weight = 0 does not show

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to create a layout with an embedded google map fragment and some information about selected markers below the map. I want the information below the map to only take up the space that it needs and give the rest of the space to the map.

As far as I understand it, `layout_weight` assigns extra space to the different widgets proportional to value given. So if I have a widget with `layout_weight = 1`, and another widget with `layout_weight = 0` the first widget will take up all the extra space, and the second will only take what it needs. So if I give the second widget `layout_height = wrap_content`, then I should get what I want. However, this doesn't seem to be the case in practice. I have changed a lot of the values, and either one of the widgets take up all the space, or neither take up any. The only way I have been able to get them to show up normally is by setting the `layout_height` of the second widget to a specific value.

This may be part of the issue, but I am populating the widgets `map_frag_event_icon`, `map_frag_person`, and `map_frag_event_details` dynamically.

---

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fragment_margins"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fragment_margins"
        tools:context=".fragment.MapFragment"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_person"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Family Map</string>
    <string name="title_activity_maps">Map</string>

    <dimen name="fragment_margins">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="horizontal_layout_padding">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="vertical_layout_padding">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="icon_size">48sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="icon_padding">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_size">20sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="small_text_size">14sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="large_text_size">24sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="map_event_layout_height">120sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="map_event_icon_size">40sp</dimen>

</resources>
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is the general design I am looking for, but I want the white space with the text to be as small as possible, and I want to create a setting to change the text size, so the the bottom white space should be dynamic.

### [image]

Please give an explanation of what is going on along with a solution if you can.

Comment: remove `android:layout_weight="0"`

Comment: Why parent `android:layout_height="0dp"` ?

Comment: @Mahammad I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: try @FaysalAhmed's solution

Comment: can you please share the design here?

Comment: @hasan_shaikh I edited the question to included an example of the design with the current issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues with my original code that I posted. I don't know when I added that during my original testing, but there were two fatal errors. In the root `LinearLayout` I had `layout_height = "0dp"` and it should have been `layout_height = "match_parent"`. And in the `LinearLayout` that contained the two `TextViews`, I had `layout_height = "match_parent"` and it should have been `layout_height = "wrap_content"`.

With those two errors fixed, @MuhammadMuzammilSharif's original comment about removing `layout_weight = "0"` worked.

---

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fragment_margins"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fragment_margins"
        tools:context=".fragment.MapFragment"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_person"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment keep the `android:layout_weight="1"` but in the LinearLayout apply, for example, `android:layout_weight="0.5"`. Check the outcome and then change the values according to your needs. Look at it a bit as relational percentages, so 1 to 0.5 would be 66% to 33%

Answer (score 0):

Try with below layout :

```
    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/map_frag_event_layout"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fragment_margins"
        tools:context=".fragment.MapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_person"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fragment_margins"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_google_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fragment_margins"
        tools:context=".fragment.MapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_person"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xml code with this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fragment_margins"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map_frag_google_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fragment_margins"
    tools:context=".fragment.MapFragment"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_person"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/map_frag_event_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your are setting weight to 1 for both the views. So